# Visio template affected by drawing scale

Tags: microsoft-visio

I created a microsoft visio template that contains a border and title block for a 11x17 page.  I find that when I open a new document using this template and adjust the drawing scale my border gets adjusted too.

How can I define my border using page size instead of drawing size?

Comment: Which version of Visio? Also, how are you adding the border and title? From the menu/ribbon or from the Title Blocks stencil?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick and dirty explanation.  First you will need to create a background that only has your border and title block.

1. Right-click on bottom tabs and click "Insert page...".  This will bring up the Page Setup dialog box.
2. Select the "Background" radio button and give it the name of "My Border".
3. Make any other preference changes while you are in this box.
4. Click OK when you are done.

Now you can use this as the background in your regular drawings.

1. Again, right-click on bottom tabs and click "Insert page...".
2. This time select the "Foreground" radio button and then for the Background pull-down choose "My Border".

This should do it.  I used this method to create a new sheet with a different scale and the title block stayed the same (which is what I wanted).  The only thing is the automated field in the title block did not update with the new scale.  I will have to figure out why.